# error during building velodyne plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was following this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i5), but as i try to build the plugin file velodyne_plugin.cc i get this error:

```
/home/rob/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::VelodynePlugin::Load(gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
/home/rob/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:23:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class gazebo::physics::Model’
         _model->GetName() << "]\n";
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/gazebo-2.2/gazebo/common/Plugin.hh:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-2.2/gazebo/common/common.hh:28,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-2.2/gazebo/gazebo_core.hh:19,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-2.2/gazebo/gazebo.hh:20,
                 from /home/rob/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:4:
/usr/include/gazebo-2.2/gazebo/physics/PhysicsTypes.hh:36:11: error: forward declaration of ‘class gazebo::physics::Model’
     class Model;
```

How can i remove this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14304/error-during-building-velodyne-plugin/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14078/cant-compile-custom-plugin/) question. The problem can be solved by adding the following include to your cc file:

```
#include <gazebo/physics/Model.hh>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on 2016-08-31**:
thank u, i searched the question list for the existing problem using the velodyne keywords, but didn't get so, i posted.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-08-31**:
No problem, I only knew about it because I see this coming up over and over again. I'll fix the tutorial today.